# Does GitHub store each object just once?

Tags: github, storage

I'm doing a project about storing lots of repositories from GitHub. There are many objects shared by many repositories. So I want to learn about if GitHub just store each object once to save storage, and how to do this(if it's not a secret).

I have not found any satisfying answer, just some predictions that GitHub has done that.

Comment: In GitHub all forked repository have shared commit id space. That means any commit pushed to any repository can be addressed from any fork of it. One way how you can do this is [namespaces](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub has **not** done this.  GitHub stores each "repository network" individually, where a repository network is:

- An original repository
- Forks of that repository

Each "repository network" can share objects between them, using Git's "alternates" mechanism.  This allows Git to consider other object database locations beyond just the normal storage within the repository.

When you create a repository on GitHub, you create a single, bare repository on disk, with a normal on-disk object database backing it up.  When you create a fork from that repository, GitHub will:

1. Create a new "alternates" area for the repository network.
2. Move the repository's objects in to the alternates area.
3. Set up the original repository to know about the new alternates area
4. Set up the new fork to know about the new alternates area.

When this happens, the repository network will share objects between them.  This means that objects are shared between the original repository and repositories that have been forked.

But this is the limit of shared object storage.  There's no big database of objects that everybody can share (nor should there be for scalability and security reasons).

(Note: although I worked on the Git Infrastructure team at GitHub, this information is not confidential.)

**Sources**

These two talks at the [Git Merge](http://git-merge.com/) conference discuss GitHub's git repository storage:

- [Scaling at GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ecUqHxD7o), a talk by Patrick Reynolds at [Git Merge](http://git-merge.com/) 2016.
- [Top Ten Worst Repositories to Host on GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZNKR9wFe8o), a talk by Carlos Martín Nieto at [Git Merge](http://git-merge.com/) 2017.
- [Counting Objects](https://githubengineering.com/counting-objects/), an article by Vicent Martí.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question as following.

Comment: Why not GitHub share objects among those repositories? Will it take too much efforts without great improvement of result? And what the thorniest difficulty will GitHub face when realizing that? Modifying the total structure of GitHub?

Comment: There's very little gains to be had by doing this.  So you deduplicate some files like "hello, world" and the MIT and GPL licenses.  Those aren't really big wastes of disk space.  Instead, you have to change Git to have some security model above the repository, where the objects "exist" in every repository, but you can't have read access to them.  Otherwise I could just walk GitHub and suck down every single object on the server (albeit slowly).

Comment: Plus, we're _going_ to see a SHA1 preimage attack.  That makes object conflicts a _reality_.  By sharding the storage to a per-repository setup, they avoid that.

Comment: But it's also the _easiest_ setup with the way Git works.  Changing this would be a lot of effort and not be valuable.